# Overloading on callable with callable parameter

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functional-programming, template-meta-programming

I am trying to translate C# code like below to C++:

```
void SomeCall(Action action)
{
   // do things like action();  

}

void SomeCall(Action<Action> action)
{
   // define some action1   
   // do things like action(action1);   

}
```

C++ equivalent of SomeCall should be able to take std::function as well as inline and outline C++ lambdas of the same signature.

After browsing many SO questions regarding overloading on C++ std::function and lambdas, it seems that
the answer should look like:

```
template<typename Func>
enable_if<Func is something callable>
void SomeCall(Func&& action)
{
 ...
}

template<typename Func>
enable_if<Func is something callable taking another callable as the parameter>
void SomeCall(Func&& action)
{
 ...

}
```

Can you help me fill in the blanks?

Comment: R.Martinho Fernandes wrote a solution much better than mine but he cba to write an answer. Here is his: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1b7ka6$1

Comment: @Seth Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 compiler doesn't like it and pops error C2995: ''unknown-type' f(T &&)' : function template has already been defined message for the second template function.

Comment: what do you mean by "TMP"?

Comment: @phresnel Template Meta Programming

Answer (score 0):

You can try using standard overloading like so:

```
void Fn( std::function<int(int)>& fn )
{
}

void Fn( std::function<int(float)>& fn )
{
}
```

If this isn't acceptable, you're going to have to do a lot of research into template meta-programming to get enable_if to work how you want, which is the most sadistic form of programming imaginable. In all seriousness though, you could try starting with Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu.

Comment: Well, Martinho's code works in all compilers except Visual C++. I submitted a bug report to Microsoft but they say it is not scheduled to be fixed anytime soon, considering the other priorities that they have. His code is pretty simple actually, but MSVC++ decltype is incomplete and buggy, not only in this respect.