# Why doesn't the overload (using enable_if) with universal reference work?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, template-meta-programming

**Using MS Visual C++ 2012 version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1:**

```
int x()
{
   return 3;
}

template <typename Fun>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Fun, int()>::value, int>::type 
MySh(Fun& f)
{ 
   return f();
}

template <typename Fun>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Fun, int()>::value, int>::type 
MySh1(Fun&& f)
{ 
   return f();
}

template <typename Fun>
int MySh2(Fun&& f)
{ 
   return f();
}
```

The calling code:

```
   int res = MySh(x); // compiles and returns 3
   res = MySh1(x); // doesn't compile with error: error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::enable_if<std::is_same<Fun,int(void)>::value,int>::type MySh1(Fun &&)
   res = MySh2(x); // compiles and returns 3
```

I haven't tried with other compilers (yet) but the intent is to get it to work with Visual C++ 2012 and/or report the compiler bug to Microsoft.

I want to make sure I am not overlooking something trivial and making a dumb mistake.
Of course, the sample is just an extract, the real intended use case is more complex and related to:
[Overloading on callables question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824681/overloading-on-callable-with-callable-parameter)

**Edit:**
I was additionally confused by other considerations such as, for ex:

```
   std::is_same<decltype(x), int()>::value; // true
   std::is_same<decltype(x), int(&)()>::value; //false
```

and:

```
template <typename Fun>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Fun, int(&)()>::value, int>::type 
MySh1(Fun&& f)
{ 
   std::cout << typeid(f).name() << std::endl;   // prints int __cdecl(void)
   return f();
}
```

Clearly, I was not paying attention to the difference between the type of the parameter and the type of the argument (Fun as opposed to f and x).

Comment: About your edit, wouldn't it be better to check the return value of the "callable", like in `std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<F>()()), int>::value`. This way you wouldn't be bothered with the actual function/functor type (whether it's a reference to function, a pointer to function, a functor, etc), only whether you can or not call it through a given pattern of arguments for a given return type.

Comment: @chico - yes, that would be great and it is in line with Yakk proposal. Unfortunately, you guys either run other compilers or am I going nuts here. I certainly can compile both yours and Yakko's versions of the code on LiveWorkspace, using Clang 3.2 or g++ 4.8.0, but not with Visual Studio.

Comment: oh ok, I was using clang 3.3... forgot about the msvc thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the error, replace your declaration with

```
template <typename Fun>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Fun, int(&)()>::value, int>::type 
    MySh1(Fun&& f)
{ 
    return f();
}
```

It happens because of the special treatments standard has for cases with template `<typename T> void foo(T&&);`

If you pass some arguments to the foo then the following holds(for int as an example):

- pass `lvalue int` -  `T` is `int&`
- pass `lvalue const int` - `T` is `const int&`
- pass `rvalue int` - `T` is `int`
- pass `rvalue const int` - `T` is `const int`

Good [article](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) of Scott Meyers may shine more light on it.

Comment: But what is a justification for it, given that:
   std::is_same<decltype(x), int()>::value
returns true? Surely enable_if should be selecting a valid int return type in this context as well?

Comment: Justification is simple: "universal references rule" lvalue becomes T& when used with template<class T> fun(T&&) and your x function is lvalue.

Comment: I understand the reference collapsing rules (or so I thought) when applied to 'simple' types but I see that I don't grasp it when the type is the free function. Can you elaborate a bit on the need for & in int(&)() signature?

Comment: It is absolutely the same. You have your function `x`, you can count is as `int` in terms of "entities" they are no different. Because you have your `x` function declared then whenever `x` is participated in others function argument it is **lvalue**, hence the rules for lvalue are applied. Try to pass `&x` and you will have to change your signature in `enable_if` to  `std::is_same<Fun, int(*)()>`. Hope this is clear, more or less

Comment: let me ponder on it a bit. I have another case where change from int() to int(&)() doesn't fix the problem but, instead of std::is_same, in that case I am using third-party utility function posted on SO in the context of similar problem.

Comment: I understand what both of you guys who answered are aiming at but I still can't wrap my mind around it. For ex: why is it that MySh(Fun& f) doesn't require the same change in enable_if?

Comment: Because `Fun&&` has special treatment and wording in standard, while `Fun&` is not. `Fun&&` is an unique case. Maybe this [article](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) will help you

Comment: @Tony simply said, it just doesn't make sense. It's put into the rvalue reference type because noone complained about it to put it somewhere else, probably new mechanism. So rvalue references are abused for it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb BTW, you may get a kick out of this: Sh in MySh stands for Schaub as I couldn't get your solution at ideone.com/ur90o to work for free functions under Visual C++ version above. So I was inclined to think it is a compiler bug. Maybe I am just not smart enough to use it but it works great for functors for me. Idea now is to use your code for functors and this code for free functions and OR it to get a complete enable_if

Answer (score 2):

A `Fun` in that context is a `Fun&` or a `Fun const&` or a `Fun&&` -- the `&&` makes `Fun` bind to any one of the above 3 references (and maybe `Fun const&&`?  Not sure).  `&&` means a magic reference in a type deduction context.

You compared it to a `int()` instead of a reference or const reference or rvalue reference to same.

I would suggest using `std::decay` if you don't care what `cv` and reference types are attached to `Fun`.

As in

```
template <typename Fun>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::decay<Fun>::type, int(*)()>::value, int>::type
```

An even better option might be `is_convertible`

```
template <typename Fun>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Fun, int(*)()>::value, int>::type
```

which allows `[]()->int` lambdas to qualify as being a usable `Fun`.  But why stop there?

```
template <typename Fun>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<Fun>()()), int>::value>::type
```

accept any type `Fun` such that an instance of `Fun`, with `operator()` applied, returns a type that can be converted to `int`.

You can even go further with one of these:

```
template <typename Fun>
auto MySh_Alpha(Fun&& f)->decltype( f() )
{ 
  return f();
}

template <typename Fun>
decltype( std::declval<Fun>()() ) MySh_Alpha2(Fun&& f)
{ 
  return f();
}
```

which are equivalent, and says that `MySh_Alpha` returns the same type as whatever `f` was passed in.

Comment: Both you guys have good answers aiming in the same direction so I have trouble deciding which answer to accept. Instead, I will try to test more, polish the question and see if there is any real compiler issue hidden here.

Comment: BTW:
`template <typename Fun>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Fun, int(*)()>::value, int>::type 

//typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<Fun>()), int>::value>::type
Yakk(Fun&& f)
{
   return f();
}` 
works fine for free functions and lambdas, not for std::function, and commented out line with decltype doesn't compile in my version of Visual C++

Comment: The first works for free functions and stateless lambdas.  The second you are missing the second `()` after `declval`.  Unless I made a typo, it should work fine with `std::function`.

Comment: yeah, need to clean glasses once in a while. There is a typo IMO and it should be:

`typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<Fun>()()), int>::value, int>::type`

but even that doesn't work. Compiler rejects left side as false right away, printing:
`error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if<_Test,_Ty>'
          with
          [
              _Test=false,
              _Ty=int
          ]`

Comment: which compiler are you using? I have no issue with your version testing online with clang 3.2, but MSVC, no luck, now or before

Comment: @tony I am not using a compiler outside my head.  I could believe that 2012 has a quirk getting in the way.  Or maybe I did a typo!  To debug that kind of code in your compiler, break it down to smaller steps.  Why the argument false?  Work with just the code within the `enable_if` and print the `bool` to `cout`.  Maybe msvc wants a real instance, maybe `is_convertable` is flawed, maybe it does not like `&&` in a function context and screws up the magic reference.  Dunno.

Comment: compiling in your head, huh?! Must be a great job :) Anyway, I posted bug report to MS here: [link to MS Connect bug page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779916/decltype-and-declval-dont-work-as-expected#tabs)